# Unity flips x coordinate in obj using importer at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime

I'm creating a `.obj` file importer at runtime in Unity3D.

The problem is that when I import a `.obj` file, it comes with the `x` coordinate flipped; by "flipped" I mean that if the `x` coordinate in a vertex in the file says `-12`, then unity reads a `12` and vice versa.

The logged coordinates look like this:

```
-42.4 -6.608938 -1.6
-42   -6.579293 -1.6
-42.4 -6.652683 -1.2
-42.4 -6.608938 -1.6
```

Whereas my original `.obj` file had vertices like this:

```
v 42.4000015258785 -6.60893774032594 -1.60000002384146
v 42.4000015258785 -6.65268325805652 -1.20000004768452
v 42.0000000000008 -6.57929277420054 -1.60000002384146
v 42.0000000000004 -6.57929277420055 -1.60000002384106
```

So, the question is, how can I prevent Unity from changing the signs of my coordinates?

Comment: Solved with: transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a similar question on gamedev.stackexchange.com. From [one of the answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/152819/93710) there:

> 1. The actual OBJ file format specification declares that, "A right-hand coordinate system is used to specify the coordinate locations."
> 2. Unity uses a left-hand coordinate system.
> 3. Conversion from right-handed to left-handed is accomplished by negating the coordinates on any axis (it doesn't matter which one).
> 4. Unity negates the X-coordinates to convert the right-handed OBJ data to left-handed data.